# Error message while using Knit in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am quite new to R and learning R for a research project of mine. I am having trouble with knitting in R Markdown.

The error message I am getting:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: ... this said: The error message is telling you that you have a duplicated chunk label, i.e. you used the label "ethipoia4_oc" multiple times. Chunk labels should be unique but there is an option to allow for duplicates: See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/duplicate-label.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.